# how do surface blur to a video using FFMPEG common line?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

[image]
[image]

like above two image , it is one frame of the video ，

origin video:https://youtu.be/Qmoc7VyX2f8

surface blur video:https://youtu.be/zbw1XVXjn4c

Is there a way to use FFMPEG common line do that , thank you very much

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't decribe it clearly before

Comment: Ran out of time to write answer but see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Postprocessing